# What kind of module can I use to show table in drupal？

Tags: drupal

I would like  to show  a  table  in  homepage. And data  in  table must  be from  database, and  refreshed dayly  automately. And only administer can modify database through  changing the  table  data. I use drupal to  make  my  website, then  what  kind of  module  can i use to  create  this  table?

Comment: Try views with 'table' as views display style. You can learn more about 'views' on documentation page

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `Views` module provides a flexible way to control the way lists and tables of `content`, `users`, `taxonomy terms`, slideshows etc are presented on your site.There is a very good video tutorial for this `views module` on how to create a `table view`.Plaese do also read the `drupal documentation` about the `views module` in the below link.

```
Documentation
```

https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views

```
Video tutorial
```

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0gxRf7CQgE